# Regex: How do I match lines that include "something", but exclude lines that start with "a", even if they contain "something" (Case insentive)?

Tags: regex, grep

I suppose this should be easy enough, but it's been a while since I've coded regex.

Say I have a file

```
This line contains something
This one doesn't
And this one shouldn't match, even if it contains something
Also, this one shouldn't match
Something is included here
Here's something else
and finally, a lower case a. Now that's something.
```

I'm using grep, and this is what I have

```
polar@UBFF:~$ tail -fn20 temp.txt | grep "[sS]omething"
This line contains something
And this one shouldn't match, even if it contains something
Something is included here
Here's something else
and finally, a lower case a. Now that's something.
```

So, can someone tell me how I modify this very simple regex, to exclude lines starting with "a" or "A", even if they include "something"?

Comment: Use `grep -P "^(?![aA]).*[sS]omething"`, or `grep -E "^[^Aa].*[sS]omething|^[sS]omething"`

Comment: With two grep: `grep -i -v '^a' file | grep -i something`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I suggest to use replace `"` with `'` because of `!`.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, `grep -P '^(?![aA]).*[sS]omething'`, just modified the pattern after copy/pasting OP code.

Comment: +1 to @Cyrus This is really simple and far more readable/understandable as two separate regular expressions. There's no law that says you have to accomplish every pattern-matching task with a single regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to respond everyone.

However, maybe I should have clarified, the lines I do not want to match (at the start of the line) is actually a string, and not a single letter. A string of numbers, really. Say "123" for example. Now, I tried modifying [aA] to [123], but obviously that excludes anything beginning with 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Same holds `^123`

Comment: I suggest to replace in my comment `^a` with `^123`.